# as I get the value of this array Json?

Tags: php, arrays, json

My code:

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_summoner);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    // get the result and parse to JSON
    $result_arr = json_decode($result, true);

    print_r($result_arr);
```

What I get on screen:

```
Array ( [21300] => Array ( [id] => 21300 [name] => Soreria [profileIconId] => 4 [summonerLevel] => 30 [revisionDate] => 1378283161000 ) )
```

As I can get just the name?

Comment: Yes. You can. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: echo `$result_arr[21300]['name']`

Comment: How 21300 is generated ?

You can do `echo $result_arr['21300']['name'];` if you have this index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get it by

```
echo $result_arr[21300]['name'];
```

but if index is not constant you can use

for php 5.5

```
$name = array_column($result_arr, 'name');
```

php 5.3,

```
$name = array_map(function ($ar) {return $ar['name'];}, $result_arr);
```

and

```
  echo $name;
```